# r shiny: create column headers with write.table in text file

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a simple shiny app, where I use three `numericInput`s. The user inputs three numbers, and in the server side I use this input to write a `.txt` file using `write.table`. In the `.txt` file I want to create column headers similar to the label of every input, so the first number to be in a column with header 1st Number etc. I thought it was gonna simple, but I am keep not getting the expected result.

My code:

```
write.table(paste(c(input$firstNum, input$secondNum, input$thirdNum), collapse = " | "),
            filename, quote = FALSE, row.names = TRUE,
            col.names = c("1st Number", "2nd Number", "3rd Number"))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are providing a single scalar (`1|3|5`) to `write.table`, it believes that you are writing a single-column table. This is obviously not what you think you are doing. The benefit of using `write.table` is that you give it a table-like structure (`matrix` or `data.frame`, typically) and it'll put in the `sep`arator.

```
write.table(matrix(c(input$firstNum, input$secondNum, input$thirdNum), nr=1), 
            filename, sep='|', quote = FALSE, row.names = TRUE,
            col.names = c("1st Number", "2nd Number", "3rd Number"))
```

where the changes are:

- provide a `matrix` instead of a pre-compacted string, and
- add the `sep='|'` argument

Comment: When I run the app locally I get the expected result, but when I run it in the shinyapps.io and download the .txt file the headers and the data are in the same line. Any thoughts why is this happening?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with `shinyapps.io` differences, I'm not well-versed.